# Can "which" be substituted with "that" in the sentence?

Tags: word-stress

The original sentence:

> In fact, however, it is the untruthful thought which is the more
>   vicious of the two.

The above sentence semantically appears to be:

> In fact, however, the untruthful thought is the more vicious of the
>   two.

If so, is there any particular reason to use "**it is...which...**" instead of the more common "**it is...that...**" structure in this context?

Comment: Your second sentence not only doesn't use *that*, but you've changed the word order—which makes a simple comparison between *which* and *that* more complex than it has to be.

Answer (score 3):

*That* is used for defining clauses (needed to provide meaning to the sentence), *which* is used for non-defining clauses (additional meaning to the sentence).

Example:

*Which fork did you use? I used the one that was in the drawer.*

*Did you use a spoon or fork? I used the fork, which was a poor choice.*

Comment: Karen, do you think it is an emphatic pattern, something like: It + be + underlined word/phrase + that/who/which clause?

Comment: @Charlie if I understand your question correctly, emphasis is shown by using an adverb (or adverb phrase) after that/who/which. "Did you use a spoon or fork? I used a fork, which, by the way, was a poor choice." "I used the one that, surprisingly, was in the drawer." To speak it, the sentence stress is on that/who/which with a brief pause before and after the adverb. 

P.S. "It + be" follows the same rules

Comment: @Karen927 In the UK, *which* can also be used in restrictive clauses. (Although even in the UK, *that* is not used in nonrestrictive clauses.)